# force close when send data to server

Tags: database, multithreading, networking, server, android-volley

I'm new to sending data to servers and working with the Volley Library.

I use the following code to send the data to the server using the Volley library in Splash Screen.

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            List<Transaction> transactionsList = transactionDao.getAllTransactions();
                            for (int i = 0; i < transactionsList.size(); i++) {
                                Transaction transaction = transactionsList.get(i);
                                String mobile = partnersDao.selectPhoneNumberById(1);
                                String traderName = transaction.getTraderName();
                                String operation = transaction.getOperation();
                                String from = transaction.getFrom();
                                double amount = transaction.getAmount();
                                String reason = transaction.getReason();
                                long transactionDate = transaction.getTransactionDate();
                                long registrationDate = transaction.getRegistrationDate();
                                long time = transaction.getTime();
                                String transactionType = transaction.getTransactionType();
                                long transactionNum = transaction.getTransactionNum();
                                String description = transaction.getDescription();
                                int searchHelper = transaction.getSearchHelper();

                                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://myhost.ir/?command=set_transactions&mobile=" + mobile + "&trader_name=" + traderName + "&operation=" + operation + "&from=" + from + "&amount=" + amount + "&reason=" + reason + "&transaction_date=" + transactionDate + "&registration_date=" + registrationDate + "&time=" + time + "&transaction_type=" + transactionType + "&transaction_num=" + transactionNum + "&description=" + description + "&search_helper=" + searchHelper, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    }
                                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                        Log.e("TAG", "onErrorResponse: " + error);
                                    }
                                });
                                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                                requestQueue.add(request);
                            }
                        }
                    }).start();
```

As long as the amount of data is small, there is no problem, but as the number of data increases, the speed of the software decreases, and after a while, force close occurs.

Also, to receive data from the server, I use the following code, which is not a problem as long as the number of data is small, but with increasing the number of data, the software speed decreases and after a while, force close occurs.

When the number of data is small, intent to MainActivity occurs in its own time, but when the number of data is high, intent starts faster than loading all the data, and as a result, the MainActivity recycler view is empty.

```
  StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://myhost.ir/?command=get_partner_info&mobile=" + mobile, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                                        try {
                                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                            String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                                            String phoneNumber = mobile;
                                            long percent = Long.parseLong(jsonObject.getString("percent"));
                                            Partners partners = new Partners(name, phoneNumber, percent);
                                            partnersDao.add(partners);
                                            name = jsonObject.getString("partner_name");
                                            phoneNumber = jsonObject.getString("partner_mobile");
                                            percent = Long.parseLong(jsonObject.getString("partner_percent"));
                                            Partners partners1 = new Partners(name, phoneNumber, percent);
                                            partnersDao.add(partners1);

                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                    }
                                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                        Log.e("TAG", "onErrorResponse: " + error);
                                    }
                                });
                                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
                                requestQueue.add(request);

                                StringRequest request1 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://myhost.ir/?command=get_transactions&mobile=" + mobile, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                                        try {
                                            JSONArray transactionArray = new JSONArray(response);
                                            for (int i = 0; i < transactionArray.length(); i++) {
                                                JSONObject jsonObject1 = transactionArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                                String traderName = jsonObject1.getString("tradername");
                                                String operation = jsonObject1.getString("operation");
                                                String from = jsonObject1.getString("from");
                                                Double amount = Double.parseDouble(jsonObject1.getString("amount"));
                                                String reason = jsonObject1.getString("reason");
                                                Long transactionDate = Long.parseLong(jsonObject1.getString("transaction_date"));
                                                Long registrationDate = Long.parseLong(jsonObject1.getString("registration_date"));
                                                Long time = Long.parseLong(jsonObject1.getString("time"));
                                                String transactionType = jsonObject1.getString("transaction_type");
                                                Long transactionNum = Long.parseLong(jsonObject1.getString("transaction_num"));
                                                String description = jsonObject1.getString("description");
                                                int searchHelper = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject1.getString("search_helper"));

                                                Log.e("TAG", "onResponse: " + "traderName: " + traderName + "operation: " + operation + "from: " + from + "amount: " + amount +
                                                        "reason: " + reason + "transDate: " + transactionDate + "registDate: " + registrationDate + "time: " + time + "transType: " + transactionType +
                                                        "transNum: " + transactionNum + "description: " + description + "searchHelper: " + searchHelper);

                                                Transaction transaction = new Transaction(traderName, operation, from, amount, reason, transactionDate, registrationDate, time, transactionType, transactionNum, description, searchHelper);
                                                transactionDao.add(transaction);
                                            }

                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }

                                    }
                                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                        Log.e("TAG", "onErrorResponse: " + error);
                                    }
                                });
                                RequestQueue requestQueue1 = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
                                requestQueue1.add(request1);

                                handler = new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        getActivity().finish();
                                    }

                                }, 200);
```

**By the way, I have not created a static RequestQueue yet and a new RequestQueue will be sent for each request. Could this be my software problem?**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Retrofit Library

***Methodology***

- Since this is about measuring the “speed” of either library. I only measure the time is takes for an asynchronous call to return the raw response.
- I selected 8 RSS feeds from a local news site measure the average amount of time it took for each library to fetch all 8 RSS feeds from a clean install.
- In order to account of network latency and other real world factors, I ran each tests 10 times and averaged the results.
- I measured each library twice to account for any network issues that may have been taking place the first time I ran the 10 tests.
- All tests were run on the Android Studio 2.0 x86 emulator running API 23 on a Nexus 5.
- For Volley, the tests were run using OkHttp 3, Apache 4.4.12 and Android platform API (for API 9+ this is URLConnection, for older versions it may be Apache HttpClient 2.0+)
- POST was testing by creating a stubbed service on my localhost. Each call time was averaged

***The result***

- Retrofit took on average 41ms to fetch the 8 API responses.
- Retrofit cache responses took an average of 21ms
- Retrofit POST with 3 fields took 14ms on average.
- Volley-native took an average of 50ms.
- Volley-native cache responses took an average of 12ms.
- Volley-native POST with 3 fields took 18ms on average.
- Volley-Apache4 took an average of 48ms.
- Volley-Apache4 cache responses took an average of 13ms.
- Volley-Apache4 POST with 3 fields took 15ms on average.
- Volley-OkHttp3 took an average of 40ms.
- Volley-OkHttp3 cache responses took an average of 14ms.
- Volley-OkHttp3 POST with 3 fields took 15ms on average.

use this link for more information:
https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/is-retrofit-faster-than-volley-the-answer-may-surprise-you-4379bc589d7c